# Pentaho - call stored procedure with 1 input parameter and Refcursor output (multiple output fields) with multiple rows

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, pentaho-spoon

I'm trying to get the output of a stored procedure in oracle that has 1 input parameter lets say DEPT_NO and get out columns DEPT_NO, DEPT_TYPE, DEPT_SERIAL, DEPT_NAME to Pentaho and load this output to another DB. The output returns multiple rows.

Please see the code for the stored procedure shown below. It returns multiple rows.

Can you please hep me with the details steps in Pentaho Spoon? Steps/how to call. 
If there is a different way to write the stored procedure and call in Pentaho? Please let me know. Thank you in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST
( P_DEPT_NO NUMBER, C_COLSOUTPUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) 
AS
BEGIN
 OPEN C_COLSOUTPUT FOR
SELECT DEPT_NO 
,DEPT_TYPE 
,DEPT_SERIAL 
,DEPT_NAME
 FROM DEPT_SP WHERE DEPT_NO=P_DEPT_NO;
END;
```

[Output of the SP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6xzu.png)

```
DEPT_NO DEPT_TYPE   DEPT_SERIAL DEPT_NAME
1       1           A           ANAME
1       1           F           FNAME
1       1           G           GNAME
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any advice if someone has cracked it.